# How to case insensitivity check in combination with lookup/graphLookup?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a query implemented in the below link wherein I am trying to get all the depots based on the `city` values present in `charge_level_key` inside `contracts`. In other words, each string value in `charge_level_key` is a city that has to be matched with the depots and the corresponding depots should be fetched.

The current implementation is working with case sensitive. I need to make it work as the same way with case insensitivity. How would I do that

https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZH6K5gkJxrs

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regular `$lookup` you can use a pipeline with `$toLower`:

```
db.contracts.aggregate([
  {$match: {_id: ObjectId("630c9e23fb146c4b3b801b9e")}},
  {$set: {
      charge_level_key: {$map: {input: "$charge_level_key", in: {"$toLower": "$$this"}}}
  }},
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "depots",
      let: {charge_level_key: "$charge_level_key"},
      pipeline: [
        {$match: {
            $expr: {
              $in: [{$toLower: "$city"}, "$$charge_level_key"]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "depots"
    }
  },
  {$sort: {count: -1}}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rCcr2RUs30g)

Comment: Just curious to know if there is any other approach that uses regex at one point so that there will be no need for lower case conversion at two places!

Comment: You can replace the `$toLower` inside the pipeline with a `$regexMatch`, but I don't think it is better. Especially when the `$in` can complicate it...

Comment: Could you give an answer using regexMatch as well just to check if possible!

Comment: I could not find a way to use a field value as pattern in a regex. The closet thing I found is `$indexOfCP` which is not suitable for this case